# statistic to assess overall correlation among a set of variables

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis

I have a set of $n$ vectors $X_i \in \mathbb{R}_m$ and am interested in a statistic that captures the overall degree of correlation among the vectors. It should be high if they're mostly all positively correlated and low if they're inversely correlated or uncorrelated. I want to use this statistic to compute a p-value empirically using a background distribution of many sets of $n$ vectors. Is there a recommended statistic for this?

An obvious possibility is just the sum of pairwise correlations between the vectors. But I'm curious if there's a name for what I want or a better choice in some sense.

Comment: What do you want the statistic to do if you have three variables A, B, and C, but A is positively correlated with B, B is negatively correlated with C, and A has near zero correlation with C? More generally, what are you trying to accomplish with this statistic?

Comment: For the case you gave, if it's just one pair that have the positive correlation, I'd like the statistic to be low. I'm looking for something that's sensitive to the case where a subset (not necessarily the whole set though) of vectors all show positive correlation with each other. It would probably involve some kind of tuning parameter that affects the tradeoff between size of the subset and the values of the correlations. Mostly interested to know if there's a name for this, since I thought it would probably have come up for others.

Comment: You might push a correlation matrix through $r_{ij}' = \max(0, r_{ij})$ and then move on from there. Just to note that this isn't, so far as I can see, a re-invention of principal component analysis, which is equally delighted by strong correlations of either sign.